# Hide a FormIo Radio option based on condition?

Tags: javascript, radio-button, formio

Is it possible to hide a radio option value based on the answer to a previous question?

For example:

Question 1 (radio): Red or Blue?

Question 2 (radio): 10 ( red only), 20(red only), (30 blue only), 40(blue only)

I don't want to show 10 and 20 if the user selects blue.

I am unable to split the second question into two because the API property needs to be the same.

Comment: can you add some example code

Answer (score 0):

Since formiojs@4 (available through https://next.form.io) components have the option to define specific logics.  Thus, you may change the component itself based on different conditions (such as events or custom javascript).

Basically, you will want to trigger the logic whenever the color component has a value (so it does not triggers unnecessary on every change).  On this change, you may update the component values depending on the value of the color.  Also, clear the component's value if the new options does not includes its current value.

You could have the following action for example:

```js
var values = [];

if (data.color === 'red') {
  values.push(10, 20);
} else if (data.color === 'blue') {
  values.push(30, 40);
}

if (!values.includes(data.option)) {
  delete data.option;
}

schema = {
  values: values.map((value) => ({ label: value.toString(), value })),
};
```

Check the following jsfiddle for a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/airarrazaval/btpyfjm8/